# How to prevent VS Code from putting '{' on new line in C++ formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I write some code

```
void function() {
....
}
```

when I format the entire page using `Shift+Alt+F`, it becomes

```
void function() 
{
....
}
```

How do I prevent that initial opening bracket from going to a new line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assuming you're using the MS C++ extension, these are the docs you're after. In > short, you'd need to either:
>
> change C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle to one of: LLVM, Google, Chromium, > Mozilla, WebKit - and see if one matches your preferences.
>
> find/make a custom .clang-format file
>
> see clang-format docs for more details: > https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/9rqj02/prevent_vscode_from_putting_c_curly_braces_on_new/